# How can I get a column from database based on the value of the column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was wondering how I can retrive an item from a database by using the value of the column, I have a database item with a column called sid, that have different values based on what it should be used for, i have one item with the sid of "description" and another with the sid value of "profile_view".
How can I get the one with the value of description by using php PDO, this is the code I am trying to use:

```
try {
    $GetSettings = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `profile_settings` WHERE profileId=?");
    $GetSettings->bindValue(1, $profileId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $GetSettings->execute();
    $SettingsData = $GetSettings->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($SettingsData as $SettingsRow) {
        $description = $SettingsRow['sid']['description'];
        $profile_view = $SettingsRow['sid']['profile_view'];
    }

} catch (PDOException $e) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$SettingsRow['sid']` is not an associative array, it's a string with the value of the `sid` column in that row. So you need to compare it with the values you're looking for, then get the value from another column.

```
foreach ($SettingsData as $settingsRow) {
    $sid = $SettingsRow['sid'];
    $value = $SettingsRow['value']; // I'm just assuming this is the name of the column with the relevant data
    if ($sid == 'description') {
        $description = $value;
    } elseif ($sid == 'profile_view') {
        $profile_view = $value;
    }
}
```